# What sealing type for cable/tube enter casing for outdoor use?

Tags: terminology, cases, environmental-sealing

I build an electronic device which is used outdoors. A bundle of cables enter the device in a small 30mm diameter tube. This tube should be sealed so no dust/water/moisture enters the casing. It should be possible to remove tube easily for maintenance without damaging the sealing, tube or casing.

See the illustration below:
[image]

Illustration legend:

- Orange: Casing
- Green: Sealing
- Blue: Tube

I assume there are common solutions for this problem and I am searching for either the correct term for this kind of sealing.

The illustration of the green sealing is just an *assumption* from my part how a such sealing could look like. It does not have to look and work this way. For me, the requirements for the sealing are:

- Seals against dust, water and moisture.
- For tube/cable with 30mm diameter.
- Removable for maintenance without damaging tube, sealing or casing.

**What standard solutions exist for this case?**

**What is the correct term for this kind of sealing?**

Comment: Consider arranging the cable entry upwards into the enclosure ... unless it can be submerged.

Comment: This would be nice, but it is on the top if the case and I can not change this. I also can not replace it with a connector, which would be nice too.

Comment: You are excluding the most common, most effective solutions that, if you look around, you will see employed all the time. Good luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The general type of thing you are looking for is a *Cable Gland*. There are different types and you might want to look at *IP ratings* to get a feel for how waterproof and dustproof you need to be.  E.g. *IP68* is waterproof and dustproof for outdoor use and short term immersion, *IP54* for outdoors but protected from the worst of the rain or in a dry climate.

You might also consider: 1) Having the cable come in through the bottom, so water running down the cable runs away from the feedthrough not towards it. 2) using a connector rather than putting a bundle of cables through a gland - this is a little more expensive but usually works out easier if it is to be regularly removed and reconnected.

Comment: Glands are usually the way to go indeed. Keep in mind that to be truly waterproof, the cable needs to be waterproof as well. Otherwise water will creep in over time through the cable itself (especially near bends). Don't forget to take care of the other side of the cable as well.